# Centralizar texto dentro de imagem

Tags: html, html5, css3

Preciso alinhar horizontalmente e verticalmente um texto dentro de uma imagem.

Algum de vocês sabe como posso fazer isso?

***HTML***

```
<img src="https://marketingdeconteudo.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/formatos-de-imagem-2.jpg">
    <p>Texto que deve ser alinhado!</p>
</img>
```

***CSS***

```
/* Não tenho a menor ideia do que fazer! */
```

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/162510/99718

Answer (score 4):

Jovem só para te esclarecer, a tag `<img>` não precisa ser fecha, logo isso é errado `<img></img>` *(Imagem é um elemento do tipo "Void" ele não pode ter nada dentro, outro exemplo é o `<input>` que também não tem tag de fechamento `</input>`)*

Agora sobre a sua pergunta uma das opções que vc pode fazer é colocar a imagem dentro de uma `<div>` que esteja com `display:flex` e usar as propriedades do flex para alinhar o que estiver dentro na horizontal com `justify-content:center` e na  vertical com `align-items:center`

**Veja o exemplo:**

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.holder {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.holder img, .holder p {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
    <img src="https://marketingdeconteudo.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/formatos-de-imagem-2.jpg">
    <p>Texto que deve <br>ser alinhado!</p>
</div>
```